# Deducing the template parameter of a templated class argument: const issue

Tags: c++, templates, constants, template-argument-deduction

I think the problem is fairly common, so there should be a known solution. I came up with one, but I'm not really satisfied, so I'm asking here, hoping someone can help.

Say I have a function, whose signature is

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const MyArray<const T>& x);
```

The const in the template parameter is to prevent me from changin the array content, since (for reasons beyond this question), the accessors (`[]` and `()`) of `MyArray<T>` are always marked const, and return references to `T` (hence, the const ensure safety, since `MyArray<T>::operator[]` returns `T&`, while `MyArray<const T>::operator[]` returns `const T&`).

Great. However, templates with different template arguments are non related, so I can't bind a reference to `MyClass<T>` to a reference of `MyClass<const T>`, meaning I can't do this

```
MyArray<double> ar(/*blah*/);
foo(ar);
```

Notice that, without a reference, the code above would work *provided* that there is a copy constructor that lets me create `MyArray<const T>` from `MyArray<T>`. However, I don't want to remove the reference, since the array construction would happen *a lot of times*, and, despite relatively cheap, its cost would add up.

So the question: how can I call `foo` with an `MyArray<T>`?

My only solution so far is the following:

```
MyArray<T> ar(/*blah*/);
foo(reinterpret_cast<MyArray<const T>>(ar));
```

(actually in my code I hid the reinterpret cast in an inlined function with more verbose name, but the end game is the same). The class `MyArray` does not have a specialization for `const T` that makes it not reinterpretable, so the cast should be 'safe'. But this is not really a nice solution to read. An alternative, would be to duplicate `foo`'s signature, to have a version taking `MyArray<T>`, which implementation does the cast and calls the const version. The problem with this is code duplication (and I have quite a few functions `foo` that need to be duplicated).

Perhaps some extra template magic on the signature of `foo`? The goal is to pass both `MyArray<T>` and `MyArray<const T>`, while still retaining const-correctness (i.e., make the compiler bark if I accidentally change the input in the function body).

**Edit 1**: The class `MyArray` (whose implementation is not under my control), has const accessors, since it stores pointers. So calling `v[3]` will modify the values in the array, but not the *members stored in the class* (namely a pointer and some smart-pointer-like metadata). In other words, the object is de facto not modified by accessors, though the array is. It's a semantic distinction. Not sure why they went this direction (I have an idea, but too long to explain).

**Edit 2**: I accepted one of the two answers (though they were somewhat similar). I am not sure (for reasons long to explain) that the wrapper class is doable in my case (maybe, I have to think about it). I am also puzzled by the fact that, while

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const MyArray<const T>& x);
MyArray<int> a;
foo(a);
```

does not compile, the following does

```
void foo(const MyArray<const int>& x);
MyArray<int> a;
foo(a);
```

Note: `MyArray` does offer a templated "copy constructor" with signature

```
template<typename S>
MyArray(const MyArray<S>&);
```

so it can create `MyArray<const T>` from `MyArray<T>`. I am puzzled why it works when `T` is explicit, while it doesn't if `T` is a template parameter.

Comment: If the accessors are `const`, shouldn't they return a const reference? Then you wouldn't need the `const T` template parameter.

Comment: Good question. See my edit.

Comment: Why can't you simply use `template<class T> void foo(const MyArray<T>& x);`?

Comment: @Evg, if I do that, then I have no help from the compiler in detecting accidental changes to the array (like e.g. because of a typo). When doing `MyArray<int> a; foo(a);`, the compiler will allow changes to `a` inside `foo`. I'd like to prevent that, by having const enforced on the input.

Comment: You should ensure this by properly using `const` overloads, not by inventing a different type. `const` member functions should not return non-const references.

Comment: @Evg, as I said, I am not the one implementing `MyArray`. It's implementation is beyond my control. Notice, however, that _there is_ a logic in their implementation: calling `operator[]` does not modify the underlying pointer, only the pointee. Depending on what you mean with "being const", their implementation does or does not make sense.

Comment: Re: "const member function should not return non-const references". I absolutely agree if the object the reference is bound to is _a member_ of the class. This case is _slightly_ different, since the pointee is technically not a member of the class. I know the developers of `MyArray` are _very smart_ c++ developers, and I know they had reasons for this choice. It's just too long to go over it here, and, as I said, changing `MyArray` is not  even under my control anyways.

Comment: For the edit2, you should ask another question normally, but for template function, parameters should "match", whereas for non template function, one user conversion is allowed (by parameter).

Comment: Ah, that's the catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stay with

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const MyArray<T>&);
```

and make sure to instantiate it with `const T` (in unitTest for example).

Else you can create a view as [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Something like (Depending of other methods provided by `MyArray`, you probably can do a better const view. I currently only used `operator[]`):

```
template <typename T>
struct MyArrayConstView
{
    MyArrayConstView(MyArray<T>& array) : mArray(std::ref(array)) {}
    MyArrayConstView(MyArray<const T>& array) : mArray(std::ref(array)) {}

    const T& operator[](std::size_t i) {
        return std::visit([i](const auto& a) -> const T& { return a[i]; }), mArray);
    }

private:
    std::variant<std::reference_wrapper<MyArray<T>>,
                 std::reference_wrapper<MyArray<const T>>> mArray;
};
```

and then

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const MyArrayConstView<T>&);
```

but you need to call it explicitly, (as deduction won't happen as `MyArray<T>` is not a `MyArrayConstView`)

```
MyArray<double> ar(/*blah*/);
foo(MyArrayConstView{ar});
foo<double>(ar);
```

Comment: `MyArray` is _veery_ close to `std::span` (which I'm not allowed to use due to portability and compiler limitations).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not allowed to change MyArray, one option is to use an adapter class.

```
template <typename T>
class ConstMyArrayView {
   public:
    // Not an explicit constructor!
    ConstMyArrayView(const MyArray<T>& a) : a_(a) {}
    const T& operator[](size_t i) const { return a_[i]; }
   private:
     const MyArray<T>& a_;
};

template<typename T>
void foo(const ConstMyArrayView<T>& x);

MyArray<T> x;
foo(x);
```

But in the end, if you can change `MyArray` to match the const-correctness you want, or switch to a class that does, that'll be the better option.

Comment: Nope. const MyArray<const T>& will make a ConstMyArrayView<const T> without any intervention.

Comment: @IdeaHat: As `foo` is template, indeed, no need to extra constructor, but `MyArray<T> x;
foo(x);` won't compile as it is not matching. `foo<T>(x);` or `foo(ConstMyArrayView {x})` would be required.

Comment: but if `foo` is not template, overload might be called ;) but `void foo(const ConstMyArrayView<int>& x);` won't accept `MyArray<const int>`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an ugly but effective way to have a function use one type, but also get the compiler to check that the same code would compile if it used a different type instead:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
struct xfer_refs_cv
{
    using type = To;
};
template <typename From, typename To>
struct xfer_refs_cv<const From, To>
{
    using type = const typename xfer_refs_cv<From, To>::type;
};
template <typename From, typename To>
struct xfer_refs_cv<volatile From, To>
{
    using type = volatile typename xfer_refs_cv<From, To>::type;
};
template <typename From, typename To>
struct xfer_refs_cv<From&, To>
{
    using type = typename xfer_refs_cv<From, To>::type&;
};
template <typename From, typename To>
struct xfer_refs_cv<From&&, To>
{
    using type = typename xfer_refs_cv<From, To>::type&&;
};

template <typename CheckType, typename Func, typename CallType>
constexpr decltype(auto) check_and_call(Func&& f, CallType&& call_arg)
    noexcept(noexcept(std::forward<Func>(f)(std::forward<CallType>(call_arg))))
{
    (void) decltype(std::declval<Func&&>()
      (std::declval<typename xfer_refs_cv<CallType&&, CheckType>::type>()), 0){};
    return std::forward<Func>(f)(std::forward<CallType>(call_arg));
}

template<typename T>
void foo(const MyArray<T>& x)
{
    check_and_call<MyArray<const T>>(
        [](auto&& x) {
        // Function implementation here.
    }, x);
}
```